# Asterisk CDR Report shows "s" in the destination field

Tags: asterisk, elastix

I have had issue on an platform for quite sometime now, when somebody calls in to ivr system, the cdr report destination field shows an 's' in place of the called number.
The inbound route for the DID is set to the ivr menu.
Here is my dial plan:
"

```
exten => 800000031,1,Set(__FROM_DID=${EXTEN})
exten => 800000031,n,Gosub(app-blacklist-check,s,1)
exten => 800000031,n,ExecIf($[ "${CALLERID(name)}" = "" ] ?Set(CALLERID(name)=${CALLERID(num)}))
exten => 800000031,n,Set(__CALLINGPRES_SV=${CALLERPRES()})
exten => 800000031,n,Set(CALLERPRES()=allowed_not_screened)
exten => 800000031,n(dest-ext),Goto(ivr-3,s,1)*
```

"

I suspect the issue is on the last line but the file is not allowed to be edited directly.

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

s is the default extension in asterisk , go through the logs and try to find out on what context that call was executed. It usually happens when you do not create a context for any specific DID in extension.conf. then the call is being routed to asterisk default context

Answer (score 2):

Use ${EXTEN} instead of s in Goto(ivr-3,s,1), Also in ivr-3 context create a dialplan using wildcard symbol. e.g

```
exten => 800000031,1,Set(__FROM_DID=${EXTEN})
exten => 800000031,n,Gosub(app-blacklist-check,${EXTEN},1)
exten => 800000031,n,ExecIf($[ "${CALLERID(name)}" = "" ] ?Set(CALLERID(name)=${CALLERID(num)}))
exten => 800000031,n,Set(__CALLINGPRES_SV=${CALLERPRES()})
exten => 800000031,n,Set(CALLERPRES()=allowed_not_screened)
exten => 800000031,n(dest-ext),Goto(ivr-3,${EXTEN},1)

[ivr-3]
exten => _X.,1,NoOp("Hello world")
```

Answer (score 0):

We have an IVR. When an external caller listens to IVR and decides to hangup before IVR ends talking, in report we see "s" as Destination. Otherwise, in report we see extension dialed after or while IVR is talking. I guess it's normal. If You have been hacked You'd see other various destinations but not "s".

Answer (score 0):

Solved on ours, there was no default destination set for the reception ring group. We pointed it back to the IVR and now no longer see the s destination.

Answer (score -1):

Most likly that mean you have been hacked. Please check that you have no guest calls enabled, contact security expert to find hole and fix it.